# How does Noise affect the results of Transfer Entropy?

Tags: inference, entropy, mutual-information, noise, statsmodels

I was reading about Transfer Entropy and came across this package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TransferEntropy/TransferEntropy.pdf

The code in the package:

```
## Intitialize two vectors of length 10001
X <- rep(0,10000+1)
Y <- rep(0,10000+1)
## Create two linked random processes. Y is independent of X,
## while X is determined in part by the previous values of Y.
for(i in 1:10000){
 Y[i+1] <- 0.6*Y[i] + rnorm(1)
 X[i+1] <- 0.4*X[i] + 0.6*Y[i] + rnorm(1)
}
X <- X[101:10000]
Y <- Y[101:10000]
## Compute the TE from Y to X
computeTE(X,Y,3,1,"MI_diff") ## should be circa 0.16 
## and from X to Y
computeTE(Y,X,3,1,"MI_diff") ## should be circa zero
computeTE(X,Y,3,1,"Correlation",0.4)
computeTE(Y,X,3,1,"Correlation",0.4)
```

I tried the example at the end of the package and got similar results as stated in the example. Then I created my own example to see the results, this is what I did

```
## Intitialize two vectors of length 10001
X <- c(1.5, rep(0,10000+1))
Y <- c(1.2, rep(0,10000+1))

for(i in 1:10000){
 Y[i+1] <- 0.6*Y[i]
 X[i+1] <- 0.4*X[i] + 0.6*Y[i]
}

X <- X[101:10000]
Y <- Y[101:10000]

plot(X,Y)
## Compute the TE from Y to X
computeTE(X,Y,3,1,"MI_diff")  ## should be circa 0.16
## and from X to Y
computeTE(Y,X,3,1,"MI_diff")
```

But I get this error : `Points with same coordinates in the X tree (add noise).`

Now my question is that, how does noise affect the result i.e the value of TE? Is it necessary that every value in the random variable should be unique?